# How to access directive parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am starting to learn AngularJS and while trying to use a custom directive.

I cant seem to get the child to read the parentScope, according to angular documentation children accesible methods should be **defined** inside the **controller** of the **parent directive**.
It looks like the changes directives are being run, but I cant seem to access the parent scope (function not defined acording to chrome).

Thanks in advance for any help

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCWKZmu22G0h2q0Ll2mK?p=preview)**

Comment: Please always post the relevant parts of your code here for viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using an Isolated scope(which is good). This statement isolates the scope from its parent

```
    scope: {
        key:'@',
        title:'@'
    },
```

Just pass the parent controller to the child like this.

```
require: '?^parentDirective'
link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
   scope.parentCtrl = parentCtrl;
}
```

And then in the parent controller modify your could like this:

```
var self = this;

self.addColumn = function(data){
    $scope.columns.push(data);
};
```

You do not have direct access to the parent scope.

Comment: tryied on both the plunker and my code and doesent seem to work(the only change I made was to add the ? in the required attribute[] was what I understood you)

Comment: wouldn't that make it so I can only have 1 of the parent directive in the page?(this evaluates to window in both link and controller)

Comment: I was in the middle of modifying my post try it again with the additional information.

Comment: Why would that limit you to only one directive per page?

Comment: ok my bad, seems like this in controller is not evaluated to window, but to the scope of parentCtrl so i'll take your answer as good.(I thougth it was the window object, that would have made addColumn a global function, thus redefined on each directive declaration). Althougth the documentation doesnt say anithing about using the "this" variable http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (last example)